# Red Hat Software Collections 1 Beta channel has 0 packages?

Tags: redhat, yum, php5, licensing

I want to install PHP 5.4 on a RHEL 6.x box as described in this Red Hat blog [post](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/08/01/php-5-4-on-rhel-6-using-rhscl/).

I have a valid subscription and have added the channel, but a `yum repolist` shows a status of 0 for the channel.

> rhel-x86_64-server-6-rhscl-1-beta                              Red Hat Software Collections 1 Beta (RHEL 6 Server x86_64)                                   0

What am I missing?

UPDATE: It looks like even though I can subscribe to the channel I have to make a special request.

That or it's a different channel. It seems to also have been referred to as "rhel-server-rhscl-6-beta-rpms" in this [article](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/08/06/using-drupal-7-with-the-php-5-4-and-mysql-software-collections/) but when I try to add that channel I get the stupid exceptions error which I take to mean that channel doesn't exist.

Red Hat really does a piss poor job of making this available. I wonder if it is intentional?

Comment: Why the down vote? If you can explain why two months later there are no packages in that channel I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: Consider using the Software Collections repository which is mirrored at Scientific Linux. More info at ftp://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6x/external_products/softwarecollections/README and http://listserv.fnal.gov/scripts/wa.exe?A2=ind1310&L=SCIENTIFIC-LINUX-USERS&P=R9835&I=-3&X=7CAA9F17853F775DDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red Hat Software Collections are, however, included in all Red Hat Developer Subscriptions including the self-supporting Red Hat Developer Suite.

Answer (score 0):

Self-Support licenses are [excluded](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/472793) from RHSCL entitlements.